# CURDATE() Not working for december

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use the following statement to select values from a mysql table:

```
$a = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM list WHERE inserted_on<=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($a))
    { //do something... 
       }
```

However the query skips the results which are from december (month 12)...

The inserted_on row looks like this (example):

```
2013-12-04 17:50:34 //edited so that it reflects an actual example 
year-month-date hour:minute:second
```

Any idea why...and maybe a solution to the problem?

Comment: What are you using date_sub and then subtracting nothing from it?

Comment: `2013:12:23` is not a valid datetime value. it should be `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` (note the dashes in the date). If you're not comparing native mysql date/time values, then you're doing STRING comparisons, and all bets are off.

Comment: @John Conde ...i forgot it there...i used to use another syntax..but then i modified it and i left that DATE_SUB there by mistake...

Comment: is the only row you are expecting to get back for December "2013:12:23 17:50:34" ?? If so, that data is NOT less than or equal to curdate() (which is 12/9/2013, for today).

Comment: @ Marc B ... sry it is a typo... in the database it is with dashes...(edited)

Comment: @BWS i said it is an example (dummy text) that value isn't in my database

Comment: What is the data type of your `inserted_on` column?

Comment: timestamp (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

Comment: Please review your question again to make sure it accurately represents the code that is not working, so we don't have to discuss typos and other malformed code. As it is now, your question still has `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)`, which doesn't make much sense. Please state whether this is an accurate representation of your current code, or not. And if not: edit the question accordingly.

Comment: edited (my actual code has that DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)...but i will remove it from there too when i will find a solution to the problem)

Comment: *"but i will remove it from there too when i will find a solution to the problem)"* - Posted code/questions should not be edited to reflect successful answers given by others. @SpiderLinked

Comment: ...guis make up your mind...some tell me to change it..some tell me not to...please answer the question and stop messing me up.. :|

Comment: @SpiderLinked: it's pretty simple: the question should accurately represent your code that is not working as expected. You are giving mixed signals as to what was accurate, and what was not. I'm still not sure whether your actual code uses `DATE_SUB( ... )` or not. You're not being clear (`i left that DATE_SUB there by mistake` and `my actual code has that DATE_SUB( ... )` is ambiguous). I'm not trying to mess you up. I'm just trying to make sure we know your actual code, so we can determine the actual culprit for you.

Comment: so..to make myself clear...at first i was using the date sub to substract days...then i modified the code arhitecture (no longer needed the interval)..but left that date_sub there and just changed it to interval 0...so now my code has that "senseless syntax" in it...

Comment: @SpiderLinked: OK, thanks for clearing that up. As it stands, the reason your code doesn't return the example row is simply because the `inserted_on` value is at a later date than `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)` (or any positive `n` in `INTERVAL n DAY`, for that matter). Your query returns rows where `inserted_on` is less than or equal to the `WHERE` clause. As it stands, your example row simply doesn't meet that requirement.

Comment: ok..let me clear that up for you ... that is only a "dummy text" i said above... the code does not work even when the date is 2013-12-02 it does not work for any date in december (sorry for not posting actual example-edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to try and take a stab at this one based on the comments left.

I'm not sure the exact result you need but either of these should suffice:

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE DATE(inserted_on) <= CURDATE();
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE inserted_on <= NOW();
```

The second one is a much better solution from a runtime perspective especially if your date is indexed.

EDIT:

Notice what I am doing here.

In the first since CURDATE() returns only 2013-01-01 for example and your field is returning a timestamp then to check for all times between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 I am essentially saying get me only the DATE of my inserted_on field and compare that to curdate().

In the second I am saying now() which will be as of the date/time of this post 2013-12-09 10:54:19 and I am comparing that to your timestamp in your table of format 2013-01-01 00:00:00 (as an example).

Comment: i will try changing to now() to see if there will be any change...

Comment: still not working... :|

Comment: Please hit edit on your question and give the exact dates you have in your table, as well as the dates that show up in your anser but should not. This query should have worked for you.

Comment: managed to make it work using NOW()....it seems that when i've changed the code to use now i deleted by mistake the "=" sign to ..my bad.. thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Given this example code, based on your examples, it works as expected with me (using MySQL version `5.0.51b-community-nt`, but that's unlikely to matter):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`list`;
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`list` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `inserted_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO list VALUES( null, '2013-12-04 17:50:34' );
INSERT INTO list VALUES( null, '2013-12-23 17:50:34' );
```

Then when I execute your query:

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE inserted_on <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY);
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE inserted_on <= CURDATE();
```

or even, for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE inserted_on <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

The result is:

```
| id | inserted_on         |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2013-12-04 17:50:34 |
```

... as expected.

So, there must be something else going on in your code, that we are not aware of. For instance:

- Are you positive that the row actually exists?
- What data type are your using for the column `inserted_on` (even though a text column should work fine as well)
- What version of MySQL are you using?
- etc.

Further question:

- What is the value of `$a` when you do a `var_dump( $a );` immediately after the exact `mysqli_query( ... )` call you have? Is it `false`?
- What is the result set when you don't use PHP, but some MySQL admin tool to directly query the database? Does is give the expected result set, then?

Comment: to answer your post: yes i am, timestamp (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) , i really don't know... and yes..i know it should have worked...this is why i am asking what could be the problem...